# How to  add root tag to the string xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(_data)
           XElement root = new XElement("student");
           doc.Element("marks").Add(root);
             doc.Save(_data)
```

the _data is the deserialized string xml and student is the root tag want to add
doc.save throws the error.How to save the root tag ?

the string xml

```
             <marks>
           <name>Martin</name> 
           <date>3/24/2012</date> 
           <field>Percent</name> 
           <new>33.3</new> 
           <old>10</old> 
            </marks>
```

this is the string xml before root tag is added, once it is added it should look like
after the root tag is added it should look like

```
             <student>
            <marks>
           <name>Martin</name> 
           <date>3/24/2012</date> 
           <field>Percent</name> 
           <new>33.3</new> 
           <old>10</old> 
            </marks> 
            </student>
```

Comment: `root` is not a very good name for an element _under_ `<marks>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `XDocument.Parse(_data)`

implies that `_data` is XML, ie `"<tag> <sub /> </tag>"`

> `doc.Save(_data)`

Requires `_data` to be a valid filename. Like  `"output.xml"`

Ok, seems that you need:

```
//doc.Save(_data)
_data = doc.ToString();
```

Take 3:

You need to add the existing xml to `<Student>`, not the other way around.

```
//untested    
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(_data);  // not XDoc
XElement root = new XElement("student", doc);
//doc.Save(_data)
_data = root.ToString();
```

Comment: we save _data as nvarchar in database, so its string how to add root tag to this string

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
var doc = new XDocument();
var root = new XElement("student");
var innerXml = XElement.Parse(_data);
root.Add(innerXml);
doc.Add(root);
_data = doc.ToString();
```

or alternatively

```
var doc = new XElement(
    new XElement("student",
        XElement.Parse(_data)
    )
);
_data = doc.ToString();
```

or a one-liner:

```
_data = new XElement(new XElement("student", XElement.Parse(_data))).ToString();
```