# How to change the root tag name in xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I need to change the xml root tag name from "string" to "TramaOutput". How to achieve this

```
public string ToXml() 
    { 
        XElement element = new XElement("TramaOutput", 
        new XElement("Artist", "bla"), 
        new XElement("Title", "Foo")); 
        return Convert.ToString(element);
    }
```

For this the output is:

```
<string>
    <TramaOutput>
        <Artist>bla</Artist>
        <Title>Foo</Title>
    </TramaOutput>
</string>
```

In the below mentioned code I am getting an error like "Cannot use wildcards at the top level of a schema."

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public XElement getXl()
        {
            XElement element = new XElement("Root",new XElement("BookId",1),new XElement("BookId",2));

            return element;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error is elsewhere - this code outputs xml without `<string>` tag. How you are saving xml?

Comment: BTW `XElement` is not `IConvertable` or `IFormattable` so `Convert.ToString(element)` internally just calls `element.ToString()`

Comment: [Click Here] [0] for reference:

This might solve your problem.

[0]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439733/how-to-add-root-tag-to-the-string-xml

Comment: @lazyberezovsky this is webservice response xml

Comment: @Vignesh create class `TramaOutput` with properties `Artist` and `Title`. Create instance of this class and send it as response. Object will be serialized into xml. Currently you are sending string, which is serialized into xml.

Comment: @Vignesh I've updated answer with complete solution

Answer (score 4):

Your code generates correct xml, there is no error:

```
<TramaOutput>
    <Artist>bla</Artist>
    <Title>Foo</Title>
</TramaOutput>
```

You see `<string>` element, because you are sending this xml as a *string data type* over the network. I.e. you receive string with content of your xml.

---

More examples - if you will send `"42"` string, you'll see

```
<string>42</string>
```

---

How to solve your problem? Create following class:

```
public class TramaOutput
{
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And return instance of it from your web service:

```
[WebMethod]
public TramaOutput GetArtist()
{
    return new TramaOutput {Artist = "bla", Title = "foo"};
}
```

Object will be serialized into your xml:

```
<TramaOutput><Artist>bla</Artist><Title>foo</Title></TramaOutput>
```

You don't need to build xml manually!

---

If you want to control process of serialization, you can use [xml attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Apply attributes to your class and it's members, like this:

```
[XmlAttribute("artist")]
public string Artist { get; set; }
```

That will serialize property into attribute:

```
<TramaOutput artist="bla"><Title>foo</Title></TramaOutput>
```

Comment: So are you implying that `return Convert.ToString(element);` creates the `<string>` tag?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud no, I'm implying that *sending* string data type creates `<string>` tag

Comment: I got you. So the process (i.e. more specifically the type sent) by which the OP is sending the data to the receiver is the issue.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud exactly :)

Comment: now i had attached the full code

Comment: @lazyberezovsky   I tried your code its working now, thanks for your help. I have an another query, if i want to use attributes for the xml tag then what should I need to do

Comment: @Vignesh you can use XmlAttribute attribute for this. See updated answer and link

Comment: @lazyberezovsky  yeah i tried that it's working but if i need to add attribute for Title tag for this case what should i need to do

Comment: @Vignesh you need title element represented as attribute, or you need title element with some attribute inside? (btw I think serialization tuning is out of this question scope)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky <TramaOutput><title name="xx">yyy</title>/TramaOutput>  , i need like this output

Comment: @Vignesh [here is sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797055/xml-serialization-question-how-to-serialize-element-attribute-and-text-from-o)

Answer (score 1):

I checked it under .net 4.5 Both

```
Convert.ToString(element);
element.ToString();
```

Are all return

```
<TramaOutput>
    <Artist>bla</Artist>
    <Title>Foo</Title>
</TramaOutput>
```

What's .NET version and XML.Linq version you are using now?